# Singapore visit visa rejected twice in 10 days

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, singapore

I am an Indian national. I have studied and worked in Singapore for close to 3 years. My EP was canceled last month and I wanted to come to Singapore now to visit friends. My short-term visa was rejected twice. I am not sure why. Please help.

Comment: Without knowing your circumstances it's hard to say why – and ICA is generally not very talkative – but your EP being cancelled is kind of a flag. What happened there? Why was it cancelled?

Comment: Being rejected twice implies you applied twice. What changed between the two applications?

Comment: EP was canceled because I have resigned from my previous job. I was not in Singapore on the day EP was canceled hence I was not issued the typical 30 days stay visa. So I applied for tourist visa the very next day the EP was canceled to visit Singapore. I applied second time after a week because I assumed first-time visa was rejected because I applied immediately after EP cancellation. No major change in visa application

Comment: @kaki What reason was given by ICA for the rejections?

Comment: No reason was given- After first rejection, they just said we can't share any reason. You can apply again if you want

Comment: VTC: impossible to respond, as ICA does not share its decisions and anything here would be pure speculation.